# How to use customized blur / focus event with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want to dispatch some redux actions when input got focus / blurred using redux-form 5.3.2.
Not sure how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As contained in redux form [docs](http://redux-form.com/6.2.1/examples/asyncValidation/), redux form accepts an `asyncValidate` callback that is run `onBlur`. The syntax looks like this:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'asyncValidation', // a unique identifier for this form
  asyncValidate: () => { /* place your custom event here */ },
  asyncBlurFields: [ 'username', 'otherFieldsYouWantToAttachTheBlurEventTo' ]
})(AsyncValidationForm)
```

Your actions can be dispatched in the `asyncValidate()` handler.